# Vector Field, Scalar Field. Which is meaningful and not?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Let a, b, c be vectors, f(x, y, z) be a scalar ﬁeld, F(x,y,z) be a vector ﬁeld. Which of the
following expressions are meaningful?

I. (a×b)×(c×b)

II. |a|(b· c) +|a|(b+c)

III. ∇ ×(f F)

IV. (∇ ×F)·(f ×F)

I know that (I) makes sense. Vector x Vector.
(II) is not meaningful

I am confused about grad and curls. I know that div and curl apply to vector fields, grad to
scalar fields.

So. curl(f F). is (f F) scalar and is (f x F) vector?

Comment: 3rd one makes sense but not the 4th one .

Comment: so III. multiplication of scalar and vector fields become vectors?
why does IV. not make sense? because you cannot do (vector)·(vector) is that correct?

Comment: You can always multiply a vector by a scalar, no problem. Check my answer concerning IV. The cross-product of a scalar and a vector is not defined.

Comment: Right it is not defined Thank you! matt

Answer (score 2):

Let's call a vector $v$ and a scalar $s$. Then we have:

1. $v\times v\quad\checkmark$
2. $s\cdot s + s\cdot v\quad \Rightarrow\text{nonsense}$
3. $v\times (s\cdot v)\quad\checkmark$
4. $(v\times v)\cdot (s\times v)\quad \Rightarrow\text{nonsense}$

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt.
so for 3. (s·v) becomes scalar.
and (s x v) becomes vector?

Comment: $(s\cdot v)$ is a vector. It's just a scaled version of the original $v$. $(s\times v)$ is not defined.

Comment: yeah vector right. I am just confused with dealing with div and curl. Your notation makes it a lot easier to understand. Thank you

Comment: Welcome. Remember this: $v\cdot v=s$ (dot product or inner product). $v\times v = v$ (cross product). $s\cdot v=v$ (ordinary multiplication).